# Printindex with biblatex prints the complet bibliography at the end of the last chapter

Tags: biblatex, imakeidx

I'm using `biblatex` to print a bibliography in every chapter of my thesis. I decided to add a "Bibliography Index" at the end of the document and I could do it following some of the suggestions written here. However I have two questions:

- The last chapter bibliography prints the complete bibliography of the thesis when using `\printindex[...]`
- The instructions followed here gave an Index by author, could it be done by titles?

Here I wrote a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot,es-tabla]{babel}

%---------------
% Used packages at the document

\usepackage {eurosym}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,labelfont=bf]{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[spanish]{minitoc}

%-------------------------------------



\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@article{Article1,
    title={Current Article 1},
    author={Someone, One and Sometwo, Two},
    journal={XXXXXXX},
    year=2015,
    volume=5,
    number=15,
    pages={15--20},
}
@article{Article2,
    title={Current Article 2},
    author={Anyone, One and Anytwo, Two},
    journal={XXXXXXX},
    year=2015,
    volume=5,
    number=15,
    pages={15--20},
}
\end{filecontents*}


%-------------------------------------
%Bibliography

\usepackage[ language=spanish,
         backend=biber,
         style=numeric-comp,
         subentry,
         indexing=cite,
         maxnames=6,
         sorting=none,
         refsection=chapter]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{jobname.bib} %addbibresource  
% -------------------------------------------------------
% Code from cacamailg to implement the index

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=authors,title=Índice Bibliográfico,columns=1]
\makeindex[name=years,title=Years Index,columns=1]

\makeatletter
% For the "years" index, we redefine the ordinary bibmacro
% which indexes titles, so that it indexes into the years
% index instead
\renewbibmacro*{index:title}[2]{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
     {\usebibmacro{index:years}%
      {\index}%
      {\undated}%
      {\thefield{indexsorttitle}}%
      {\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {\usebibmacro{index:years}%
      {\index}%
      {\thefield{year}}%
      {\thefield{indexsorttitle}}%
      {\thefield{entrykey}}}}

\newbibmacro*{index:years}[4]{%
    \begingroup
     \protected@edef\theindexentry{%
      \unexpanded{#1}\yearsindex{#2!#3\actualoperator\unexpanded{\citefield}{#4}{indextitle}}}%
     \theindexentry
     \endgroup}

% For authors we just redefine the field format (so that it
% includes title and year information
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {\usebibmacro{index:name}%
      {\index}%
      {#1}%
      {#3}%
      {#5}%
      {#7}%
      {\thefield{indexsorttitle}}%
      {\thefield{entrykey}}%
      {}}
   {\usebibmacro{index:name}%
      {\index}%
      {#1}%
      {#3}%
      {#5}%
      {#7}%
      {\thefield{indexsorttitle}}%
      {\thefield{entrykey}}%
      { (\thefield{year})}}}
% ... and modify the relevant bibmacro to add the extra information
\renewbibmacro*{index:name}[8]{%
  \begingroup
  \ifuseprefix
    {\protected@edef\theindexentry{%
       \unexpanded{#1}\authorsindex{%
         \ifblank{#4}{}{#4 }%
         \@firstofone #2% remove spurious braces
         \ifblank{#5}{}{ #5}%
         \ifblank{#3}{}{, #3}%
         \actualoperator
         \ifblank{#4}{}{\MakeCapital{#4} }%
         #2%
         \ifblank{#5}{}{ #5}%
         \ifblank{#3}{}{, #3}!#6
            \actualoperator\unexpanded{\citefield}{indextitle}#8}}}%
    {\protected@edef\theindexentry{%
       \unexpanded{#1}\authorsindex{%
         \@firstofone #2% remove spurious braces
         \ifblank{#5}{}{ #5}%
         \ifblank{#3#4}{}{,}%
         \ifblank{#3}{}{ #3}%
         \ifblank{#4}{}{ #4}!#6\actualoperator
            \unexpanded{\citefield}{#7}{indextitle}#8}}}%
  \theindexentry
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\yearsindex}{[years]}
\newcommand{\authorsindex}{[authors]}

%-------------------------------

\begin{document}



\chapter{Chapert 1}
\minitoc %indice capítulo


cite{Article1}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, title={Bibliografía}]%, section=5]% 


\chapter{Chapert 2}
\minitoc %indice capítulo


cite{Article2}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc, title={Bibliografía}]%, section=5]% 





\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addstarredchapter{Índice Bibliográfico}


\printindex[authors]
%\printindex[years]


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have never created an index with `biblatex` and don't really have an idea what you are talking about. Would it be possible to add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) (for MWEs with bibliographies see [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864))  that shows the issue and can give us a feel for what you are doing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on point 1? Is that a complaint? Do you only want a chapter bibliography?

Comment: The first point can be remedied by adding a `\newrefsection` before `\addstarredchapter`. Because otherwise the "citations" done in the index (not sure if that is how it should work) send their items to the bibliography in the last chapter; but then they have a refection of their own and don't bother us.

Comment: To clarify your second question: Do you want an index where you can only see the title of a work and then the page numbers?

Comment: If you kick out all the code related to indices in your MWE, just load `\usepackage{imakeidx}\makeindex` and issue `\printindex` in the end you get an index with authors and titles. Is that closer to your need?

Comment: Hi @moewe ! For question 1 your comment works ok. Thank you very much. For question 2, you are right but   `\printindex` prints all titles (without anyother details like author, journal,...)  and authors at the same time. I would like to show only titles with their details.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "titles" with their details? That almost sounds like a complete bibliography?

Comment: Yes, it would be a complete bibliography showing the pages in which they are cited (some of them are cited in two or more chapters). As I could read at the biblatex manual (or at least as I understood) it has to be done in this way.

Comment: If you are open to using `refsegment` instead of `refsection` we can have a real bibliography will all titles at the end. But then of course the numbering will be global, i.e. citations in chapter two will not start with [1] again.

Comment: Good, I take your suggestion. But I keep trying to do it in this way. Thank you :)

Comment: Mhhh, I would have added an answer to do it with `refsegment`s. (Would you be interested in one?) I really don't feel abusing the index in such a way is a good idea.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to have a `refsection` bibliography for each chapter and a `refsegment` bibliography for the complete document?

Comment: No, that is as far as I know not possible. A `refsection` keeps its contents completely local, it cannot be accessed from the outside. A `refsegment` is global and can be accessed from outside that section, but of course you will have to keep labels unique. I will see what I can come up with tomorrow.